# sql inner Join with Count() and windowing functions

Tags: sql-server-2008, count, inner-join, window-functions

```
;WITH n AS  
( 
  SELECT problemID, StationName, problemCode, ProblemCreateDate, probCount, 
    c = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY StationName, problemCode), 
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER  
    ( 
      PARTITION BY StationName, problemCode ORDER BY ProblemCreateDate DESC, problemID DESC 
    ) 
  FROM dbo.tblProblems
) 
 SELECT problemID, StationName, problemCode, ProblemCreateDate, c 
 FROM n WHERE rn = 1;
```

there is another table named `tblCustomers` , with a column `isAssistent` Type(`bit`)

I tried doing inner join but it's too complicated for me and I get an error when trying to apply the filter of `inner join` with

```
tblCustomers where tblCustomers.isAssistent =1
```

I will be very grateful and happy to know how to write the correct syntax

## ReEdit

```
inner join tblCustomers on tblProblems.CustID = tblCustomers.custID
```

errors , with one of my last tries

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 14 The multi-part identifier
>   "tblProblems.CustID" could not be bound. Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1,
>   Line 12 The multi-part identifier "tblproblems.problemID" could not be
>   bound. Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 12 The multi-part identifier
>   "tblproblems.custID" could not be bound. Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1,
>   Line 12 The multi-part identifier "tblproblems.StationName" could not
>   be bound. Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 12 The multi-part
>   identifier "tblproblems.problemCode" could not be bound. Msg 4104,
>   Level 16, State 1, Line 12 The multi-part identifier
>   "tblproblems.ProblemCreateDate" could not be bound.

this is the wild guess i made :

```
;WITH n AS  
( 
  SELECT tblCustomers.*,tblproblems.problemID, tblproblems.StationName, tblproblems.problemCode, tblproblems.ProblemCreateDate, tblproblems.probCount, 
    c = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY tblproblems.StationName, tblproblems.problemCode), 
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER  
    ( 
      PARTITION BY tblproblems.StationName, tblproblems.problemCode ORDER BY tblproblems.ProblemCreateDate DESC, tblproblems.problemID DESC 
    ) 
  FROM dbo.tblProblems
  inner join tblCustomers on tblProblems.CustID = tblCustomers.custID
) 
SELECT tblCustomers.*, tblproblems.problemID, tblproblems.custID, tblproblems.StationName, tblproblems.problemCode, tblproblems.ProblemCreateDate, c 
FROM n 
inner join tblCustomers on tblProblems.CustID = tblCustomers.custID
WHERE rn = 1;
```

the purpose was to have select result of tblProblems only when tblCustomers.isAssistent=1

Comment: can you post error that is thrown?

Comment: redtiting the post with pk info

Comment: The outer `SELECT` is referencing alias `tblProblems`, but should be referencing `n`.  It will also be returning data from `tblCustomers`, but not the way you expect since it is `JOIN`ed in the outer `SELECT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query outside with is wrong, it should be

```
SELECT tblCustomers.*, n.problemID, n.custID, 
           n.StationName, n.problemCode, n.ProblemCreateDate, c 
FROM n 
inner join tblCustomers on n.CustID = tblCustomers.custID
WHERE rn = 1;
```

And why are you joining tblcustomers again?

You can just do:

```
;WITH n AS  

( 
  SELECT tblCustomers.*,tblproblems.problemID, tblproblems.StationName, 
         tblproblems.problemCode, tblproblems.ProblemCreateDate,
         tblproblems.probCount, 
    c = COUNT(*) OVER 
        (PARTITION BY tblproblems.StationName, tblproblems.problemCode), 
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER  
    ( 
      PARTITION BY tblproblems.StationName, tblproblems.problemCode
      ORDER BY tblproblems.ProblemCreateDate DESC, tblproblems.problemID DESC 
    ) 
  FROM dbo.tblProblems
  inner join tblCustomers on tblProblems.CustID = tblCustomers.custID
  WHERE tblCustomers.isAssistent =1

) 
SELECT n.* FROM n where rn = 1
```

If you need only problems data

```
;WITH n AS  

( 
  SELECT tblproblems.problemID, tblproblems.StationName, 
         tblproblems.problemCode, tblproblems.ProblemCreateDate,
         tblproblems.probCount, 
    c = COUNT(*) OVER 
        (PARTITION BY tblproblems.StationName, tblproblems.problemCode), 
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER  
    ( 
      PARTITION BY tblproblems.StationName, tblproblems.problemCode
      ORDER BY tblproblems.ProblemCreateDate DESC, tblproblems.problemID DESC 
    ) 
  FROM dbo.tblProblems
  inner join tblCustomers on tblProblems.CustID = tblCustomers.custID
  WHERE tblCustomers.isAssistent =1

) 
SELECT n.* FROM n where rn = 1
```

Comment: now it is good no errors but the querry is other way around than what was in original without inner join, i need the problems Columns but now it draws the tblCustomesrs Fields insted Of tblProblems

Comment: actually i see now that it's there too tblProblems.* (sorry tblCustomers has over 30 Columns) but i will just not call them in the Gridview select command

Comment: what i needed was only to alter rs. answer to custid instead of *

Comment: Thanks ALOT RS who ever you are and where... you are in my language A CANNON !